# React SideEffect out of useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

the effects (increment the value of r and log it) works as expected within the useEffect hook

```
import React from "react";

let r = 0;

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);

  function handler() {
    setState(!state);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    r += 1;
    console.log("rendering:-", r, " times");
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handler}>render</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

but outside of useEffect hook the effects work unexpectedly. value of r increments by 2 rather than 1

```
import React from "react";

let r = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);

  function handler(params) {
    setState(!state);
  }

  r += 1;
  console.log("rendering:-", r, " times");

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handler}>render</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

but why???
could someone explain me please.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function body was actually invoked 2 times for the strictMode rapper in index.js

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

according to the [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

Answer (score 0):

`r` is still incremented by 1, however

> Note:
>
> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in
> certain cases where a workaround can be used.

You can read more on that here: [detecting-unexpected-side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

Here's a code example which shows, that `r` is incremented by 1:

```
import React from "react";

let log = console.log
let r = 0;
export default function App() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);
    console.info('render');

    function handler(params) {
        setState((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }

    r+=1;
    log("rendering:- r=" + r);
    log("rendering:- state=" + state);

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => handler()}>render { state }</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: in my case it is still incrementing by 1 though, thanks for the response

Comment: What version of react ar you using, and what build? Could you make a demo?